# Minimum weapons to kill Ganon (Minor BotW Spoilers)

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

What is the minimum weapons required to kill Ganon? The weapon choices should be based on how easy they are to get (no master sword) and assuming no divine beasts have been completed. The less Korok seeds, the better.

Comment: I don't have the time (or patience) to watch the whole thing, but take a look at [this speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5yJHXmuAlQ), in which the player beats the entire game from start to finish in about an hour.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to defeat Ganon with 0 korok seeds.

Comment: The point of the question was what weapons would you need to deal enough damage to kill Ganon, which without getting moderately difficult weapons to obtain, may require korok seeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a silly question on the surface because each weapon has a different damage value and number of uses. You could easily get away with a single weapon if it has high enough damage and durability, especially if you supplement it with attack-boosting effects.

But the actual (somewhat more interesting) answer to this question is **zero**. You can go into the Calamity Ganon fight with no weapons at all and still win. This because of two things:

- Shields. As long as you have a shield and good timing, you can reflect the Guardian Beams.
- Bombs. Even if you have no weapons and no shields, your infinite supply of bombs will eventually get the job done. (It'll take forever though.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are some weapons in the post-blights phase of the Ganon Fight.